# sales_flat_order table "created_at" field time not adjusted to time zone

Tags: magento-1.8, database

I have placed a test order at 09:40 AM on 16/04/2015 from front-end and the time in the Magento back-office is correct but in the sales_flat_order table "created_at" field time is wrong which is 08:40 AM. I understood that time zone is not adjusted to GMT+1. can anyone please tell me how do i adjust to GMT +1 for sales_flat_order table. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error.

Times are stored in the database in UTC and the front/admin side converts to the right timezone on the fly at display.